# Using require in html JS file and it worked! Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed a node package:

```
$ npm truffle-contract
```

It has a file truffle-contract/dist/truffle-contract.js file which can be used in HTML.  When I look at the file, I can see that it is using REQUIRE to load other packages from the npm.

```
var ethJSABI = require("ethjs-abi");
```

I thought other files had to be used by using an include as require is node.js specific?

It has this at the top:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)r....
```

Can anyone explain how it is working/done?

Even if it is somehow loading the other packages, I don't understand how it is doing that given I installed the packages local rather than global and apache is running as a different use.

Full file here:
https://gist.github.com/ianmonkuk/d969f52019ec602ca2a6d55231a27919

Thanks, Ian

Answer (score 0):

That's [**browserify**](http://browserify.org/) wrapper function:

> Browsers don't have the **require** method defined, but Node.js does. With
>   Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that
>   you would use it in Node.

So you write modular code the **CommonJS** way and then browserify it so you can use your code in the browser.

Read More: http://browserify.org/